# How to make different webpages have different background using react (Backgriound should be maintained after refreshing as well)

Tags: reactjs

Home.js file

```
const Home = () => 
{   
    var navigate = useNavigate();

    const move = () => {
        navigate("/builder");
        var change = document.getElementsByTagName('html');
        change[0].style.backgroundImage = "linear-gradient(to top, #370514, #722423, #a95026, #d3861d, #ebc512)";
    }
    return(
        <div className="fullpage">
            <div className="middle"> <h1>Undirected Graph Maker</h1>
                <div className="aligner">
                    <button type="button" onClick={move} className="btn">Unweighted</button>
                    <button type="button" onClick={move} className="btn">Weighted</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

export default Home;

This only changes the background on the button click and does not preserve it

Comment: You can have a state to store the background and on cliking the button update the state. Which will rerender the component and new background wil be applied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have declared a variable to store the initial background of the div. This is assigned to the React component state called background.
So, Whenever the state update on button click. it update the background of the div also.

```js
function Home() {
  const initialBackgroundColor =
    'radial-gradient(circle, rgba(63,94,251,1) 0%, rgba(252,70,107,1) 100%)';
  const [background, setBackground] = useState(initialBackgroundColor);

  return (
    <div className="fullpage" style={{ background }}>
      <div className="middle">
        <h1>Undirected Graph Maker</h1>
        <div className="aligner">
          <button
            type="button"
            onClick={() => {
              setBackground(initialBackgroundColor);
            }}
            className="btn"
          >
            Unweighted
          </button>
          <button
            type="button"
            onClick={() => {
              setBackground(
                'linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(34,193,195,1) 0%, rgba(253,153,45,1) 100%)'
              );
            }}
            className="btn"
          >
            Weighted
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
export default Home
```